# Is there nudity in WWE '12?

Tags: wwe-12

I've seen what the history of the WWF and what activities those divas did. Thankfully, it was censored. I'm against nudity though. Is there any nudity in WWE '12?

Comment: If the ESRB rating says nothing of nudity, it's a safe bet that there is no nudity. I do not know what the ESRB rating is, however.

Comment: For the record, this is not a sock puppet of mine.

Comment: @AndrewEckert I have removed the word Purchasing as what to buy recommendations are off topic for this site and some people did not appear to bother reading what your question is after that, which is about game content and is valid.

Comment: @Andrew: If you have a new question to ask, ask it separately instead of overwriting one of your other questions. That's not [how the site works](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: You're against nudity? I wonder how you manage hygiene.

Answer (score 9):

**No, there is no nudity in WWE '12**.

[Here](http://www.esrb.org/ratings/synopsis.jsp?Certificate=31582&searchkeyword=wwe) is a link to the ESRB page for WWE '12. The rating mentions Mild Suggestive Themes, but from the rating summary, it sounds like it is due to this:

> Some women are depicted in outfits that expose moderate amounts of cleavage.

Comment: I think the downvote brigade is getting a little carried away, or am I missing something and my answer is actually incorrect?

Comment: Personally, I'd hardly call "moderate amounts of cleavage" as 'coming close' to nudity, but that's me.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I agree. I updated my answer to be more clear.